# React Redux Call action within action and get return value

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to call and action from an action to get a database record by name, then I want to use the ID of the role record in the SignUp action that is currently being called .

How can I reuse the code for my GetRolebyName action from within the sign up action, I was trying to avoid doing the same APi request in two places.

Essentially I am just trying to look up the RoleId when creating a user.

Role actions:

```
export const fetchRoleByName = name => async dispatch => {
    const response = await db.get(`/roles?name=${name}`);

    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_ROLE,
        payload: response.data[0]
    });
};
```

Sign up Action:

```
export const signUp = values => async (dispatch, getState) => {
        const role = await dispatch(fetchRoleByName(values.userType))

        const response = await db.post('/users/',
            {
                ...values,
                roleId: role.id
            }
        );

        dispatch({
            type: SIGN_UP,
            payload: response.data
        });

        history.push('/');
    };
```

**Solution:**

As pointed out by Kaca992, the fetchRoleByName action never actually returned anything so the change required was as per below;

```
export const fetchRoleByName = name => async dispatch => {
    const response = await db.get(`/roles?name=${name}`);

    const data = response && response.data && response.data[0];

    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_ROLE,
        payload: data
    });

    return data;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside fetchRoleByName just return response. Return from dispatch is the return value of the inner function:

```
export const fetchRoleByName = name => async dispatch => {
    const response = await db.get(`/roles?name=${name}`);

    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_ROLE,
        payload: response.data[0]
    });

    return response; (or return response.data[0] if that is the role object you want, but then I would recommend writing it like this: response && response.data && response.data[0] just in case of hitting an unexisting value from db)
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh of course! I assumed the dispatch method would return but I can see now you have pointed it out, the action does not actually return anything, just updates the store. Thanks, feel a bit stupid for asking now!

Comment: @WraithNath no problem, glad I could help.